# Eight Socket Server (E7 v2) vs Two Socket Server (E5 v2) Performance

Tags: performance, cpu, intel, ram

We have a single threaded application that is performing mainly numerical calculations.

We ran this application on the following machines:

(1) Dell 2 Socket (E5-2667 v2) server with 32 GB RAM (1833 Mhz)

(2) IBM 8 Socket (E7-8891 v2) server with 32x8 GB RAM (1600 Mhz)

The application is CPU-bound. Here is a comparison of the chips:

http://ark.intel.com/compare/75273,75259

We were shocked to see that the 8 socket server is about 6 times slower than the 2 socket server!

We are unsure whether the E5 is just much more optimized for floating point calculations (in a way that doesn't show up in the clock speed or cache). Or, maybe it has to do with the way 8 socket server accesses memory (more hops to access RAM). Or, maybe it is something else. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here?

Some more details:
When we did this performance comparison, the machine was only running this one single-threaded task. We were just testing to compare single-core performance amongst the two machines. We were running a compiled c++ program in a linux environment. We expected both machines to perform similarly because the clock speed, cache size, and memory were all roughly similar between the E7 and E5 chips.

Comment: This is extremely hard to answer without a lot more detail about your application, what else the computers are doing and maybe even traces etc. However one thing that is worth nothing is if the task is really single threaded it can only run on one core at a time so a single very powerful CPU, would be better than multiple less powerful CPU's for your particular case (again depending on the OS, language etc - for example a single thread Java task may still benefit from multiple cores for some of the JVM or framework tasks that go on in the background).

Comment: When we did this performance comparison, the machine was only running this one single-threaded task. This is not the real-world usage scenario. This was just a test to compare single-core performance. We were running a compiled c++ program in a linux environment. We didn't expect the 8 socket server to perform better because it had more cores. We expected it to perform similarly because the clock speed, cache size, and memory were all roughly similar between the E7 and E5 chips.